# The way of configuring Maven settings

Tags: xml, maven, gradle

I am a person who develops Android using Kotlin and XML. It seems that the way of including the following code in Gradle has changed:
`repositories { maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } }`

It appears that the new approach involves using the assignment operator like this:
`repositories { maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } }`
Is this correct?

When I configured Gradle with the following code, it seemed a bit unusual but it worked.
`repositories { maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } }`
Could you please let me know if there are ways to further optimize the pieChart?

Answer (score 1):

The way did not change if you use the same DSL language.

But while the first snippet you showed is Groovy DSL, the latter is Kotlin DSL which by now is the recommended default DSL.

You have one more option in the Kotlin DSL that you might like more eventually, which is

```
repositories { maven("https://jitpack.io") }
```